# Simple Backbone.js Router? (page hierarchy + query string)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, query-string, client-side, router

**How do I set up a Backbone router that can handle URLs such as:**

```
example.com/#!/story-1/?a=1&b=2
```

or preferably with sub-page URL support:

```
example.com/#!/chapter-1/story-1/?a=1&b=2
```

I basically want a simple way to define pages with an associated query string.

Is this supported by default or should I make use of this or other addition?
https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/668

The end result should be something like:

1. Requested resource:
   example.com/#!/chapter-1/story-1/?a=1&b=2
2. Parse and see if it matches page in pages object:
   pages : {
     chapter-1_story-1 : {
        template : #template1
     }
   }
3. Load page template and page controllers with query string:
   PageController.load(template, params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

```
For example, a route of "search/:query/p:page" will match a fragment of 
#search/obama/p2, passing "obama" and "2" to the action. A route of 
"file/*path" will match #file/nested/folder/file.txt, passing 
"nested/folder/file.txt" to the action.
```

So therefore you can use variables like this:

```
 routes:{
   'search/:query/:page': 'handlePages'
 }
```

or paths like this:

```
 routes:{
   'search/*path': 'handlePages'
 }
```

I am not aware of any query string handling however.

Answer (score 2):

@jhudson8 from the [pull request #668](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/668) creates the [backbone-query-parameters](https://github.com/jhudson8/backbone-query-parameters) plugin.

It is very easy, just copy backbone.queryparams.js to your environment and include after backbone.js.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to draw another route that also includes '?' and a splat for the pseudo url params. For example, this is a function that you can extend Router with, that will go through your routes object and draw an additional route for each with a query string. It will also parse the url params and pass them as the final argument to the route method.

```
mapRoutesWithParams: function() {
  _.each(_.keys(this.routes), function(route) {
    this.route(route+'?*params', // draw the route with a query string
      this.routes[route],
      function() {
        var args = _.toArray(arguments);
        var params = args.pop();
        var paramsObject = _(params.split('&')).reduce(function(memo, pair) {
          memo[pair.split('=')[0]] = pair.split('=')[1]; return memo;
        }, {});
        return this[this.routes[route]].apply(this, args.concat(paramsObject));
      }
    );
  }, this);
}
```